# Counting 2 Querysets Deep within Django Template

Tags: django

Is there a way to count within a Django template on a 2nd deep queryset connected via FK's/M2M's? For instance,

Model A is FK'd to Model B, and Model B is M2M'd to Model C

```
    {% for C in Cs %}
       {% for B in C %)
         {% if B.A.all.count >= 2 %} B Has multiple A's!
         {% else %} B only has 1 A! {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Basically, I want to count the number of A's within B, and if it's 2 or more, just display "Multiple," as actually listing them out is disrupting my template. But I can't seem to get it to work. At the same time, the below **DOES** work for me:

```
    {% for C in Cs %}
         {% if C.B.all.count >= 2 %} C has multiple B's!
         {% else %} C only has 1 B! {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I just can't get it to go one queryset deeper. Any help? Do I have to do this within the views?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `B.a_set.count`? But nevertheless, a *template* is *not* the place to implement business logic, you need to do that in the *view*.

Comment: Set count did not work -- it works in the other direction, but not this way. Is there a resource where I can read about how to put this sort of logic within a view?

Answer (score 0):

You should just count it in the views.py and send it to your page in dict form.

```
count = B.A.all().count() 
return render(request, 'page.html', {'count':count})
```

But if you insist on using template, try: `{% if B.A.count >= 2 %}` no need for "all"

Comment: But I need to count the amount of "A"s for EACH B, which I'm displaying via a {% for %} loop, so counting it once in the views won't work. How do I count it for each individual one? And I tried that {% if %} code, unfortunately it doesn't work.